# I am founding "not found /etc/locale.conf " issue in my pc

Tags: 14.04

```
root@tony-Satellite-C665:~# ls /etc/locale.conf
ls: cannot access /etc/locale.conf: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can simply create this file and add your desired configuration to it, like:

```
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
```

Or whatever you want. Actually, by default this file does not exist on my machine too.

The other file that I believe `systemd` uses is:

```
/etc/default/locale
```

If you set a locale using `localectl` like:

```
localectl set-locale LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8
```

It will be add to that file:

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale 
LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8
```

Remember that you can allways get a list of available locales by `localectl list-locales` or: `locale -a`.

And if the locale you are looking for is not in the list, first uncomment it from: `/etc/locale.gen`, then run `locale-gen`, and use `localectl` or whatever why you prefer to set your preferred locales.

Comment: Just for the record, maybe some missing locales must be generated - for example: `sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"`.

Comment: @SpasSpasov, thanks for remembering that... also updated the answer.